# How to expand custom YAML config variables in Nest.js

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, nestjs

I have a simple Nest.js app and would like to use YAML configuration because of possibility to represent nested objects instead of flat .env.

I followed the Nest.js documentation about [custom configurations](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files) and [expandable variables](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#expandable-variables). Here is my custom config yaml:

```
app:
  port: 3000
  url: http://localhost:${app.port}
```

Here is how I load configuration:

```
import * as yaml from 'js-yaml';

export default () => {
  return yaml.load(
    readFileSync(
      join(__dirname, 'env/config.local.yaml'),
      'utf8',
    ),
  ) as Record<string, any>;
};
```

```
import configuration from './config/configuration';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
      expandVariables: true,
    }),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And how I'm getting the configuration:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
  getConfig(): string {
    return `App port: ${this.configService.get<string>('app.port')}, app url: ${this.configService.get<string>('app.url')}`;
  }
}
```

And the result is: `App port: 3000, app url: http://localhost:${app.port}`

I believe the variable expansion does not work by default, because I override default `load` function in `ConfigModule.forRoot`, right? Is there a way to use YAML configuration and have variables expanded automagically (eg like in Serverless configs)? Maybe using different YAML loader?